# JavaFX Alert Border

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am currently designing a GUI with JavaFX and style it with css. However, the alert behaves very strangely, as a matter of fact, the border is bugging around when pressing certain buttons or changing the focused window. It also doesn't completely draw the border, I suspect it has something to do with the image.

The formatting in the .css:

```
.dialog-pane {
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-border-color: #e2e2e2;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
}
```

The initial state of the Dialog:

[image: Initial Dialog]

The Dialog after pressing 'tab' a few times:

[image: Bugged Dialog]

The borders are somewhat hard to make out here due to them being so light, but the white space that is inserted in the second screenshot isn't actually the same colour as the border. (it is simply white whereas the border is #e2e2e2)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found [a bugreport](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095678) that states that this is actually a bug for JDK versions below 8.60 (I was working on an older laptop and didn't bother updating - I see that was stupid now).

So simply updating it to the newest version fixed this for me, no additional steps required.